# pass id of controls running at server in .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Head part**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function ChangeColor1(elementid) {
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img2.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img1.JPG')";
}

function ChangeColor2(elementid) {
document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
document.getElementById("<%= imgchange.ClientID%>").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img2.JPG')";
}
</script>
```

Body part

```
  <table >
<tr>
<td id="img1" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor1(this.id)" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="img2" runat="server" onmouseover="ChangeColor2(this.id)" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="imgchange" runat="server">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here all is working fine but when i place the above script in **.js file** it does not get working.

I think so that when i used to do onmouseover on img1 its id get passed but the id="img2" and id="imgchange" is not passed to the .js file

so this problem occurs.
how shall i pass my control id="img2" and id="imgchange" on doing onmouseover to id="img1"

Comment: after placing the script in another file have you included the file to html

Comment: Never seen people posting the same homework before :P Your teachers allow this these days?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi how shall i get control id in .js file???

Comment: @Amith my page extension is .aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be elegant.

You can declare variable in JavaScript like your aspx page

```
<script>
   var img1 = '<%= img1.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

In your external js file, use these variables

```
 document.getElementById(img1).style.backgroundImage
```

EDIT:

In aspx page

```
<script>
   var img1 = '<%= img1.ClientID%>';
   var imgchange= '<%= img2.ClientID%>';
   var imgchange= '<%= imgchange.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

In JavaScript file

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function ChangeColor1(elementid) {
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
        document.getElementById(img2).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
        document.getElementById(imgchange).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img1.JPG')";
    }

function ChangeColor2(elementid) {
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
        document.getElementById(img1).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
        document.getElementById(imgchange).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/img2.JPG')";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried putting function ChangeColor1(elementid) {

    var img1 = elementid;
    var img2 = '<%= img2.ClientID%>';
    var img3 = '<%= imgchange.ClientID%>';
    document.getElementById(img1).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/1.jpg')";
    document.getElementById(img2).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
    document.getElementById(img3).style.backgroundImage = "url('images/2.jpg')";
  
} in .js file but img1 is working fine while img2 and img3 is not working

Comment: @MiteshJain, I have updated code try these

Comment: it has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I must say, 
the question is not too much obvious or clear, but, when you have this method in abc.js file, you must include abc.js in your HTML.

i.e.

```
<script src="..<path>/abc.js"></script>
```

Comment: that i had done . but think so my id of td id="img2" and id="imgchange" is not passing to .js file

Comment: Why not do alert(document.getElementById('img2')) and for imgchange too... and see. also see if your document's onload has to do something with it

Comment: i have tried using    alert(document.getElementById("img1")); but it shows on alert [object HTMLTableCellElement]
 and alert(document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID%>")); this shows blank ,  I have put in the script of onmouseover of img1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because the js extension is not registered to be processed by isapi.dll, which is needed for Asp.Net engine to replace those calls with appropriate values.

See this article about how to configure IIS for this:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/isapicgirestriction/add

Comment: thank you for answering but i dont think so thats it was help full to me

Comment: Ok, go ahead, but there is only two solutions as I see it: mine, or using static id for your controls. It's up to you ignoring my advice, soon or late you'll come back here! ;-)

Comment: hey i had never ignored your advice. I think so i am not getting from that link as i am fresher. can u help me using another solution??

Answer (score 0):

Let see the problem again. js files are statically served by IIS, with no process. aspx files instead are passed to aspnet_isapi.dll, then are processed and the result is what is sent to client. The piece of code

```
"<%= img2.ClientID%>"
```

is not javascript, it's Asp.Net code. When this code is inside an Asp.Net page, it's interpreted by aspnet_isapi.dll and replace by control id assigned by Asp.Net to the control in client. 
But when this code is moved to an js file extension, it's served directly, without been processed by aspnet_isapi.dll, that's why Asp.Net code is not changed for the control's ids.

So far, you can see my previous link about how to make js file extension be passed to aspnet_isapi.dll or you can see this other link about how to make your Asp.Net controls's ids static, so you can remove the "<%= img2.ClientID%>" code from js and replace for the appropriate value yourself.

http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Hope this is clear now.